# .NET Excel Interop Set Excel Line Seriese Marker Transprancy

Tags: excel, vb.net

Set transparency on Excel line chart series markers.

I'm looking to create via Excel Interop in VB.NET a barcode chart in Excel.  To achieve this I'm using a line chart with the lines removed and a series per marker.  To achieve the final result I need to add transparency to the markers.

I've tried using the: `SeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.Transparency  = 0.75` However this seems to have no change to the chart.

I'm also using the following to set the marker colour
 `SeriesCollection(i).MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(70, 70, 70) .SeriesCollection(i).MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(70, 70, 70)`

Thanks for any advice :)